# What is the command to force all migrations in Django?

Tags: django, database-migration

I switched database names, and now my Django models are out of sync with my database tables. What is the command to force Django to perform all migrations to sync up the models and the tables? I don't want manage.py migrate --fake.

Comment: To run all migrations you do `python manage.py migrate`. But I don't get what is your current situation. You changed `database names` does that mean you changed your database? If you switch to another database, you shouldn't have any tables in there don't you? Why do you need to force it?

Comment: The database I switched to does have tables in it, but they are slightly different; they correspond to an earlier version of the Django models.

Comment: Then you need to `--fake` to the exact migration that matches your current database, and apply all the other migrations. You can migrate to a specific migration using `manage.py migrate <app_name> <migration_name>`. However, migrations are no magic tool to fix your database when you screw up.

Answer (score 8):

I fixed this by manually deleting all the migrations and running makemigrations again to get a new initial migration file. Then, I went into my database and manually dropped all the tables that Django created in the app. Finally, I deleted all of the rows in the table django.migrations that included the app name. After all that, I ran manage.py migrate and the database was in sync.

Answer (score 0):

When you change something in your models you must execute:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

for creation new changed schema of your models. Then:

```
python manage.py migrate <app_name>
```